# c# Http Request KeepAlive Request Order

Tags: c#, web-services, http-headers, load-balancing

My question is regarding Http Headers `Connection: Keep-Alive` and `Connection: Close`

I am calling a web service. The web service is hosted on a multiple servers and is load balanced.
The requests are kept on the same server if a the `Connection` header is set to `Keep-Alive`

My program needs to perform **two operations** (2 calls to the service) - but I need to make sure that **those two requests are sent to the same server**.

For Example if there were 3 servers behind the load balancer:

1. Request#1 (Operation#1) - calls the service and is routed to Server#1
2. Request#2 (Operation#1) - calls the service and is routed to Server#1
3. Request#3 (Operation#2) - calls the service and is routed to Server#2
4. Request#4 (Operation#2) - calls the service and is routed to Server#2
5. Request#5 (Operation#3) - calls the service and is routed to Server#3
6. Request#6 (Operation#3) - calls the service and is routed to Server#3
7. Request#7 (Operation#4) - calls the service and is routed to Server#1
8. Request#8 (Operation#4) - calls the service and is routed to Server#1
9. etc....

So my question is:

In which requests do I need to send `Close`/`Keep-Alive` in order to make the above happen?

Does `Keep-Alive` prepares the server for the **NEXT** request? Or is it telling the server to remember the **PREVIOUS** request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use it at least on the first request for each operation:

- First Request: `Connection: Keep-Alive`
- Second Request: `Connection: Close`

If you're going to do all the calls together you can also keep it in all of them but the last one, this will speed up a bit the connection process:

- First Request: `Connection: Keep-Alive`
- Second and beyond: `Connection: Keep-Alive`
- Last Request: `Connection: Close`

However it'll also depend on the load balance implementation, but I assume they tend to follow the standards.

Comment: Yep that is correct. `Keep-Alive` prepares the server for the NEXT request. And `Close` will close the connection after the request is complete.